# confidence interval symbols refinement

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, confidence-interval, errorbar

The values of my confidence interval of variable `SIZ` are very close to zero, so when I plot the graph, the circle which represents the average value overlap the intercept line.

Would anyone knows how I can decrease the size of this circle or increase the `X-axis` scale refinement so that the line of the intercept is over 0.0000, so that there will be no overlap between it and the circle?

I also would like to fill the `confidence interval` symbols of negative values in `red` and positive values in `blue`. Do you know which code should I add in my script?

Thank you very much

```js
   dput(read.table("clipboard",sep=";",header=TRUE))
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(Dataset,aes(x=est,ymin=min, ymax=max, y=mean, shape=est))

#Added horizontal line at y=0, error bars to points and points with size two
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0, size = I(1.1), color = I("red")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min, ymax=max), width=0, color="black") + 
  geom_point(aes(size=2)) 
#Removed legends and with scale_shape_manual point shapes set to 1 and 16
p <- p + guides(size=FALSE,shape=FALSE) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(20, 20, 20, 20))

#Changed appearance of plot (black and white theme) and x and y axis labels
p <- p + theme_light() + xlab("Levels") + ylab("confident interval")
#Final adjustments of plot
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
               axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1.3)),
               axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
               panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
               panel.grid.major=element_blank()) 

#To put levels on y axis you just need to use coord_flip()
p <- p+ coord_flip()
print(p)
```

```html
est min max mean
SOU -1.988 -1.893 -1.9405
EXP 0.324809225 0.354699871 0.339754548
AMOU 0.078056746 0.08289443 0.080475588
SIZ 0.009487689 0.009808696 0.009648193
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please provide a reprex of the data set? e.g dput(DATASET). I cannot import the snippet into R

Comment: Kresten, I'm not sure if I did what you ask, but please, try again now.

Comment: What ment is to publish the result of the command 'dput(Dataset)' which will enable us to copy/paste the input data. And experiment with different solutions. Did any of the suggestions in the answer work for you?

Comment: I wrote right now in my script dput(read.table("clipboard",sep=";",header=TRUE))
Do you think it will work?
Well, about the answer, I changed the circle size, but it is still overlapping the line. About the color, I lowded a new picture here, so you can see what I want to do. :)
Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to decrease the point size you will have to set a smaller size param e.g. 
 `geom_point(size = 0.2)`. Alternativly you can also control the thickness of the hline.
For the different colors of the error bar try
`geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min, ymax = mean), color="red") + 
 geom_linerange(aes(ymin= mean, ymax=max), color="blue")`

```
p <- ggplot(Dataset,aes(x=est,ymin=min, ymax=max, y=mean, shape=est))

#Added horizontal line at y=0, error bars to points and points with size two
p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept=0, size = 0.2, color = 'red') +
 geom_linerange(aes(ymin=min, ymax = mean), color="red") + 
 geom_linerange(aes(ymin= mean, ymax=max), color="blue") + 
 geom_point(size=0.2)

#Removed legends and with scale_shape_manual point shapes set to 1 and 16
p <- p + guides(size=FALSE,shape=FALSE) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(20, 20, 20, 20))

#Changed appearance of plot (black and white theme) and x and y axis labels
p <- p + theme_light() + xlab("Levels") + ylab("confident interval")
#Final adjustments of plot
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
           axis.title.x=element_text(size=rel(1.3)),
           axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
           panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
           panel.grid.major=element_blank()) 

#To put levels on y axis you just need to use coord_flip()
p <- p+ coord_flip()
p
```

[image]

```
structure(list(est = c("SOU", "EXP", "AMOU", "SIZ"), min = c(-1.988, 
0.324809225, 0.078056746, 0.009487689), max = c(-1.893, 0.354699871, 
0.08289443, 0.009808696), mean = c(-1.9405, 0.339754548, 0.080475588, 
0.009648193)), .Names = c("est", "min", "max", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Kresten, thank you very much. About the color, I add now a new plot and so you can see what I want to do. I guess the way you suggest I could get a different fill than I want.